# Efficient way to subset rows in R for dataset with 10^7 columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with dimensions 100 by 10^7.

When I do

```
    trainIndex <-
      caret::createDataPartition(
        df$status,
        p = .9,
        list = FALSE,
        times = 1
      )
    outerTrain <- df[trainIndex]
    outerTest  <- df[-trainIndex]
```

Subsetting the rows of df takes over 20 minutes.

What is the best way to efficiently subset this?

This may seem like a duplicate, but I cannot find any solutions for this.

Comment: Are you sure you can't fit a decent model on the first 10^6 lines of your data?

Comment: The "outer" is actually because I am doing feature selection on this before fitting a model. I have to consider all variables in the outer cross validation to not bias the model though.

Comment: Are you saying you have 10^7 features and 100 samples?

Comment: That is correct. My features are actually larger features broken down by a string kernel, hence the high dimensionality.

Comment: No statistical classification/regression model will provide meaningful results in this case of 100 observations and 10^7 features! Perhaps dimensionality reduction (e.g. PCA, LDA, ...) is a way forward to reduce your feature space prior to modelling.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I don't think that's strictly true. If there is a true large effect then you will probably find - with feature selection and cross validation. That there are many many many possible models that predict. Unfortunately absent a true effect you are probably going to find a predictive model that overfits with so many features. With some applications ie genomics you then have to apply common sense and say to yourself -does this look real? are these features sensible?

Comment: @StephenHenderson I would tend to disagree with you, but admittedly given the amount of information from OP it's difficult to make a statement here. As an applied statistician I remain sceptical. On a side note, also in genomics/bioinformatics you'd rarely be able to make any meaningful inference when faced with data involving 100 observations with 10^7 features. Don't get me wrong, obviously you can fit a (any) model; but parameter estimates would have large uncertainties, and/or your predictive performance will be extremely low. So I agree with your last statements on model evaluation.

Comment: @I think I basically agree. Its just we need to be careful not to imply that we somehow magically get less information as we add more measurements. Rather we just have to be more and more careful and skeptical.